# Need Apache's SCRIPT_URL equivalent in nginx + php-fpm

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, zend-framework

I'm moving a legacy Zend Framework application over to Nginx + php-fpm. Here are my relevant configs:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name *.sandbox.journalexperts.com;
  port_in_redirect off;
  server_tokens off;
  autoindex off;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/assets.conf; # this file contains some info about not access logging robots.txt, favicon.ico, etc.

  client_max_body_size 15m;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;

  root /wwwroot/vhosts/$host;
  index index.html index.php;
  access_log off;

  # deliver a static 404
  error_page 404 /404.html;
  location /404.html {
      internal;
      root html;
      allow all;
  }

  # Deliver 404 instead of 403 "Forbidden"
  error_page 403 = 404;

  # Deny access to hidden files
  location ~ /\. {
      deny all;
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
  }

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;

      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
      fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
      fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
      fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
      fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
      fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
}
```

This is my fastcgi.conf file:

```
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_split_path_info
fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URL $script_url; # This is a mapped variable.
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URI $scheme://$http_host$script_url; # Uses above mapped variable.

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PHP_SELF           $uri;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
```

I need to mimic the behavior of SCRIPT_URL and SCRIPT_URI as they are populated in Apache. I found [this thread](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,224829,224900#msg-224900) where the poster used `map` to fill these.

```
map $uri $script_url {
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php|html))(?<path_info>.+)$ $path_info;
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php|html))$ $script_filename;
}
```

This, unfortunately, does not work for me and shows /index.php as the SCRIPT_URI. I suspect that this is because of my try_files block where I send the request over to /index.php. This is supported by the Nginx documentation:

```
$uri
This variable is the current request URI, without any arguments (see $args for those). This variable will reflect any modifications done so far by internal redirects or the index module. Note this may be different from $request_uri, as $request_uri is what was originally sent by the browser before any such modifications. Does not include the protocol or host name. Example: /foo/bar.html
```

Okay, let's try rewriting the map using `$request_uri`.

```
map $request_uri $script_url {
    default $request_uri;
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php|html))(?<path_info>.+)$ $path_info;
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php|html))$ $script_filename;
}
```

This is slightly better but still does not achieve the desired result.
Here's what I get in Apache:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']: /tos/show.php/article/0000
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']: http://example.com/tos/show.php/article/0000
```

This is what I get in Nginx:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']: /tos/show.php/article/0000?hello=world
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']: http://example.com/tos/show.php/article/0000?hello=world
```

I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Fixing the PHP code wasn't an option?

Comment: Sadly, no. That was my preferred solution, but it turns out that a few different legacy applications use these two variables, as do some third party libraries we use, and who knows what else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, which works.

nginx.conf, in the http{} block:

```
map $request_uri $my_script_url {
    default $request_uri;
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php))(.*)?$ $script_filename; #/test.php or /test.php?hello=world
    ~^(?<script_filename>.*)(\?.*)$ $script_filename; #/tos?hello=world
    ~^(?<script_filename>.*)(\?.*)?$ $script_filename; #/tos or /tos/hello/world or /tos/hello/world?omg=what
}
```

Things I learned:

- the regular expressions are matched top down and processing stops when the first match is found.
- the nginx documentation could have done a lot more for me than it actually did.

Inside the server{} block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~* \.php(.*)?$ {
    include /etc/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;
    [...]
}
```

fastcgi.conf:

```
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_split_path_info
fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URL $my_script_url;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URI $scheme://$http_host$my_script_url;

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PHP_SELF           $uri;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

try_files $uri =404;
```

php.ini:

```
; cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to strip the query parameters off:

```
map $request_uri $script_url {
    default $request_uri;
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php|html))(?<path_info>.+)(\?.*)?$ $path_info;
    ~^(?<script_filename>.+\.(php|html))(\?.*)?$ $script_filename;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't change anything for me. To verify that the new pattern was matched, I changed the default to '/whatever' and that's what ended up getting returned.